# Compressing concentric cylinders with relative position unchanged

Tags: mesh, soft-body, compression

I would like to use softbody physics to compress concentric cylinders. However, the inner cylinder deformed out of place. I would like to keep the relative positions between inner cylinder unchanged, meaning they are still concentric after compression. I tried  to flip the normals of the outer cylinder to be inside, it seems not reacting with the plates anymore. I tried to perform boolean cut the cylinders first and used the difference for soft body physics. It works for some cases, but not. And the process is a little complicated. Any hints will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you _Solidify_ a single-skin cylinder instead? You could vary the thickness over time.. maybe even automate that with a weight-map..

Comment: Sounds great. I will try it out. Thank you!